# Solving an integral by parts, answer different from the template

Tags: calculus, integration

Can someone help me understand where I'm going wrong in the integral $$\int \frac{xe^x}{(x+1)^2}$$.

$$u=xe^x$$
$$du = xe^x+e^x$$
$$dv = \frac{1}{(x+1)^2}$$
$$v = \int \frac{1}{(x+1)^2}$$, which, by substitution, is $$v = - \frac{1}{x+1}$$.

Then, doing the integration by parts:

$$\frac{xe^x}{(x+1)^2}+\int - \frac{xe^x+e^x}{x+1} =\frac{xe^x}{(x+ 1)^2}+e^x$$

The result is different from the template. Did I miss something?

Comment: Remember that an antiderivative is only defined up to the addition of a constant. In other words, the difference between the final function you wrote down and any other should be a constant. Can you work that out?

Comment: Shouldn't it be $...-e^x$?

Comment: What template? I give us the information to help you. Isn't it $uv-\int v\,du?$ Note the minus. The signs cancel, so you get the result you get on the right, but your left is wrong.

Comment: @Vasili The right side is correct, the left side should be $-\int$ not $+\int.$

Answer (score 3):

The error is you have $u\frac{dv}{dx}-\int v\,du,$ whereas it should be $uv-\int v\,du.$

This should then be $$-\frac{xe^x}{x+1}+e^x=\frac{e^x}{x+1}$$